# Finish the onClick method and the on value

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using cloud functions and realtimeDatabase of Firebase. I have the problem that when a game finish, a custom dialog is open for clicking it a playing another game.

```
$reiniciar.on("click", function () {
    $casilla.css("display", "flex");
    $footer_casilla.css("display", "none");
    let dentro = false;
    if(!dentro) {
        ruta_partida.on("value", function (snapshot) {
            dentro = true;
            const datos = {
                turno_global: 1,
                casillero: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                ganador: 0
            };
            ganador = snapshot.child("datos").val().ganador;

            if (ganador !== 0) {
                ruta_partida.child("datos").set(datos);
                let casillero = snapshot.child("datos").val().casillero;

                turno_jugador.textContent = "Espere a que el rival reinicie";
            } else if (ganador === 0) {
                ruta_partida.child("datos").update(datos);
                if (turno === 1)
                    turno_jugador.textContent = "Su turno";
                else if (turno === 2)
                    turno_jugador.textContent = "Espere su turno";
                let casillero = snapshot.child("datos").val().casillero;

            }
        });
    }
    casillero_viejo = [
        0,0,0,
        0,0,0,
        0,0,0,
    ];
});
```

The problem is that when the game appears  I cant do anything because when I do it, the database have to change and this method restart the database always

Comment: Could you precise more what is the goal of your function and what does not works?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the `once()` method instead of the `on()` one, as follows.

With the on() method, the callback will be triggered for the initial data **and again** whenever the data changes. See the documentation for these two methods [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on)  and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once).

```
ruta_partida.once(function (snapshot) {
            dentro = true;
            const datos = {
                turno_global: 1,
                casillero: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                ganador: 0
            };
            ganador = snapshot.child("datos").val().ganador;

            if (ganador !== 0) {
                ruta_partida.child("datos").set(datos);
                let casillero = snapshot.child("datos").val().casillero;

                turno_jugador.textContent = "Espere a que el rival reinicie";
            } else if (ganador === 0) {
                ruta_partida.child("datos").update(datos);
                if (turno === 1)
                    turno_jugador.textContent = "Su turno";
                else if (turno === 2)
                    turno_jugador.textContent = "Espere su turno";
                let casillero = snapshot.child("datos").val().casillero;

            }
        });
```